# Remove a section in my current Invoice template in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to remove "supplier address" & "place of supply" in my current invoice template which gets generated. Please check the screenshot below

[image: Order Invoice template]

```
<?php namespace Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf;use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\Collection;class Invoice extends AbstractPdf{protected $_storeManager;

protected $_localeResolver;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
 * @param Config $pdfConfig
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\Factory $pdfTotalFactory
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\ItemsFactory $pdfItemsFactory
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer $addressRenderer
 * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface $localeResolver
 * @param array $data
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
    Config $pdfConfig,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\Factory $pdfTotalFactory,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\ItemsFactory $pdfItemsFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
    \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer $addressRenderer,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface $localeResolver,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_localeResolver = $localeResolver;
    parent::__construct(
        $paymentData,
        $string,
        $scopeConfig,
        $filesystem,
        $pdfConfig,
        $pdfTotalFactory,
        $pdfItemsFactory,
        $localeDate,
        $inlineTranslation,
        $addressRenderer,
        $data
    );
}

/**
 * Draw header for item table
 *
 * @param \Zend_Pdf_Page $page
 * @return void
 */
protected function _drawHeader(\Zend_Pdf_Page $page)
{
    /* Add table head */
    $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
    $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
    $page->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.5));
    $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
    $page->drawRectangle(25, $this->y, 570, $this->y - 15);
    $this->y -= 10;
    $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0, 0, 0));

    //columns headers
    $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Products'), 'feed' => 35];

    $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('SKU'), 'feed' => 290, 'align' => 'right'];

    $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Qty'), 'feed' => 435, 'align' => 'right'];

    $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Price'), 'feed' => 360, 'align' => 'right'];

    $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Tax'), 'feed' => 495, 'align' => 'right'];

    $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Subtotal'), 'feed' => 565, 'align' => 'right'];

    $lineBlock = ['lines' => $lines, 'height' => 5];

    $this->drawLineBlocks($page, [$lineBlock], ['table_header' => true]);
    $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
    $this->y -= 20;
}

/**
 * Return PDF document
 *
 * @param array|Collection $invoices
 * @return \Zend_Pdf
 */
public function getPdf($invoices = [])
{
    $this->_beforeGetPdf();
    $this->_initRenderer('invoice');

    $pdf = new \Zend_Pdf();
    $this->_setPdf($pdf);
    $style = new \Zend_Pdf_Style();
    $this->_setFontBold($style, 10);

    foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
        if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
            $this->_localeResolver->emulate($invoice->getStoreId());
            $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore($invoice->getStoreId());
        }
        $page = $this->newPage();
        $order = $invoice->getOrder();
        /* Add image */
        $this->insertLogo($page, $invoice->getStore());
        /* Add address */
        $this->insertAddress($page, $invoice->getStore());
        /* Add head */
        $this->insertOrder(
            $page,
            $order,
            $this->_scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
                self::XML_PATH_SALES_PDF_INVOICE_PUT_ORDER_ID,
                \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                $order->getStoreId()
            )
        );
        /* Add document text and number */
        $this->insertDocumentNumber($page, __('Invoice # ') . $invoice->getIncrementId());
        /* Add table */
        $this->_drawHeader($page);
        /* Add body */
        foreach ($invoice->getAllItems() as $item) {
            if ($item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) {
                continue;
            }
            /* Draw item */
            $this->_drawItem($item, $page, $order);
            $page = end($pdf->pages);
        }
        /* Add totals */
        $this->insertTotals($page, $invoice);
        if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
            $this->_localeResolver->revert();
        }
    }
    $this->_afterGetPdf();
    return $pdf;
}

/**
 * Create new page and assign to PDF object
 *
 * @param  array $settings
 * @return \Zend_Pdf_Page
 */
public function newPage(array $settings = [])
{
    /* Add new table head */
    $page = $this->_getPdf()->newPage(\Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
    $this->_getPdf()->pages[] = $page;
    $this->y = 800;
    if (!empty($settings['table_header'])) {
        $this->_drawHeader($page);
    }
    return $page;
}
```

Comment: See in `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php` file.

Comment: @DhadukMitesh I found the file but what to edit in that, will paste the code up on the post.

Comment: Have you install any custom module for invoice pdf?

Comment: No its default which is getting generated

Comment: `Supplier Address` and `Place of Supply` is display from custom module. So please check that where it come from.

Comment: Any idea where can i check that, as the developer working on this project has left it in midway. So i need to figute out.